# maven - anypoint studio fails to load a maven module inside a mule project

Tags: maven, mule, maven-3, anypoint-studio, mule-component

I've created a custom Mule extension, and I wanted to test it by loading it into a mule demo project as a mule-plugin.
I'm using Anypoint Studio 7.9.0, I have Maven 3.6.3 installed.

I run `mvn clean package` to create the .jar of my custom mule extension, and then `mvn clean install` to install it into my local Maven repository.

When I go to `{mule demo project} -> Manage Dependencies -> Manage Modules -> Add module from Maven` and try to add my custom mule extension to the mule demo project in which I want to test it, I get this error: `Failed to resolve module {groupID}:{module name}`

Frankly, I'm stuck here for some time now, and cannot figure out what I'm missing.

Here's the pom.xml of my custom mule extension:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>custom-mule-extension</artifactId>
<version>0.1.1</version>
<packaging>mule-extension</packaging>
<name>Custom Mule Extension</name>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.mule.extensions</groupId>
    <artifactId>mule-modules-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.3</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.14.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And this is the pom.xml of my mule demo application:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>elastic-demo</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>mule-application</packaging>

<name>elastic-demo</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

    <app.runtime>4.3.0-20210322</app.runtime>
    <mule.maven.plugin.version>3.5.1</mule.maven.plugin.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.maven.plugin.version}</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-sockets-connector</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
        <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-http-connector</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.25</version>
        <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>custom-mule-extension</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.1</version>
        <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>anypoint-exchange-v2</id>
        <name>Anypoint Exchange</name>
        <url>https://maven.anypoint.mulesoft.com/api/v2/maven</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
        <name>MuleSoft Releases Repository</name>
        <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
        <name>MuleSoft Releases Repository</name>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

The custom-mule-extension `<dependency>` element is the one that cannot be resolved. As you can see from the snippet above, I inserted the dependency directly into the pom.xml file after the "Add modules" way from Anypoint Studio UI failed. And here, I get the error that the module cannot be resolved.

One thing that bothers me is: when I launch the `mvn clean install -DskipTests` command, there is one [INFO] log that doesn't look good, and it's the one saying `No primary artifact to install, installing attached artifacts instead.`
The build goes fine, and the dependency pops up into my local maven repository, but then I cannot add it to the mule demo project.

Any help or advice would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your extension is already in the application's pom. Does the application build correctly?